# How do I access a method in a class with 2 parameters defined on @Interface line in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I have an Objective-C MacOS project containing a class  `NSImage+Rotated`.

The class **.m** file contains the line `@implementation NSImage (Rotated)` and the **.h** file contains the line `@interface NSImage (Rotated)`.

How can I access methods in this class from a different class?

Comment: Hint: you can also use NSView's `rotateByAngle:` of the image presenting view in case you just need a rotation of the view without the need to change the image. Well, unless you wanted to export a rotated image somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Import your `#import "NSImage+Rotated.h"` in the class you want to use it, next use the extension properly like this:

```
[[NSImage imageWith...] imageRotated:90];
// or better
NSImage *rotatedImage = [[[NSImage alloc] initWithData:theData] imageRotated:90];
```

where `imageRotated:(float)` is **your extension method** you want to use.

`[NSImage alloc] initWithData:theData]` is just an example, change with your real method.

Comment: The dot notation does not show extension properties - typing imageWith. does not show method in NSImage+Rotated as options but [imageWith ...} works OK.

Comment: The method works fine where the image to be rotated is defined with `NSImage * image = [[[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filename] imageRotated:rotationAngle`  but `NSImage *rotImage = [ImageView.image imageRotated:rotationAngle]` returns a blank image. Seems as though the extension does not work properly with the ImageView image.

Comment: Code for NSImage+Rotated imageRotated method is taken from  https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/13671254/

Comment: @SimonKravis the `...` dots are here as example because in your question there are no methods explained. So I used a generic one, just to make you understand how to use, of course you should use you real method instead of the `...` and next use the `rotated` extension method (as before, `rotated` is an example, you should change with your real method.

Answer (score 1):

You asked:

> How can I access methods in this class from a different class?

Your other class should simply import the `@interface` (but not the `@implementation`) of your [category](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html). E.g. the `.m` of your other class should:

```c
#import "NSImage+Rotated.h"
```

The compiler will successfully recognize the category’s various methods within that `.m` file.

Answer (score 0):

This are not Parameters, in Objective-C they are called **Category**.

read more in those [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Category.html)

In Fact you use them all the time

```
@interface SomeClass 
@property NSString* someString;
-(int)someGetterMethod;
-(void)setSomeStringWith:(NSArray*)array;
@end
//------------------------
@implementation SomeClass () // <-- empty Category name
//...
@end
```

As you see the empty category name is addressing/declaring the baseclass of course. So when you have imported a named category you are extending or changing this empty named category.

You need to import your extending category class where you want to access the given methods or changes to the baseclass

```
#import "NSImage+Rotated.h"
```

Then just call the methods as usuall.
As you didn't give an example of method declarations in your **Rotated Category of NSImage** you do not call the Category anywhere directly.
But you can call its methods once the category has extended the baseclass by instancing an NSImage.

**Means just importing the `NSImage+Rotated.h` already changes the predecessors declaration where you do so, often there is nothing to call to make it work.**
You just allocate your NSImage with `[NSImage alloc]` or `[NSImage imageWith...`

Comment: An empty Category is called a [Class Extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW3). A Category adds methods to an existing class, not to a empty named category.